# Configure Exchange to receive email from an internal address with an external IP address

Tags: exchange, spf, email

Our company provides email marketing services. Our service is hosted and emails are deployed from our IP addresses. Clients use their email address(es) as the "from" address, and typically, as long as they have the SPF record in place that includes our IP addresses, there isn't a problem with deliverability. We have one client that cannot receive emails deployed from our IPs on their internal network when one of their company addresses is the From address. The client is using exchange 2010.

Example: 
Client deploys an email to recipient: bob@theclient.com
From our server (and IP) using their from address: clientServices@theclient.com

-The email is not delivered. 
-The client has included our SPF in their DNS record
-If we use any other sending address from an outside domain, it is delivered without issue.

The client uses Postini, and has indicated that clientServices@theclient.com is white listed there, and the email is not getting caught and quarantined anywhere in Postini, so it appears that it is getting passed through, and dying at the Exchange server level. We don't believe Postini is the problem.

Is there a setting in Exchange that needs to be set for that address, or server wide that would have a positive impact on the scenario described above?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not ending up on Postini?  It's possible that your bulk email services have ended up in blatant spam blocking (BSB) on Postini which will be blocked before the email ends up in the users quarantine.  You can have the client disable BS or set it to "bounce" it which should show up as an ERROR 571 Message Refused on your outbound mail server.  The BSB setting can be changed under orgs and users-> click on the org in the list -> Spam Filtering-> should be the first set of options on the page.  These instructions will only work if your client is using old school postini and not the new google integrated option which prevents access to the older postini support portal (login.postini.com)

Comment: Thanks, we'll take a look at that with them. If it ends up in BSB, is that a directory that they can look in to see the email that has been trapped or does it just disappear into the ether?

Comment: BSB has an option to simply make it vanish.  It will depend on how it is configured.  Have you looked at your outbound SMTP logs to see what the disposition of the email was as it was delivered to postini?  Also, the Postini portal seems to indicate if the source is whitelisted it should bypass the BSB, so this might be a wild goose chase. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks, I think we've determined its not Postini in this case now, and are looking for an Exchange policy that might be nuking it.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on exchange policies that we may need to edit for this question? I'm not familiar enough with exchange to know what to edit or where to look.

Comment: You'll probably need to look in Org Config -> Hub Transport -> Accepted Domains and check to make sure the domains are in there. (they most likely are).  Second place is Server config -> Hub transport-> click on hub transport server-> receive connector below. Then verify network/authentication are not being blocked.  Though from your description, I don't think this is your issue.